# Deleting two adjacent elements and replacing them with a single element from a vector

Tags: c++, vector

So i want to find two adjacent elements(last and first are adjacent) from a vector such that their sum is minimum and after replace them with a single element=their sum. This should be done until one element remains.

I wrote a function to find the smallest adjacent pair and return the lower index. Then moved all the elements after that index one place and used a.resize(n-1).
The code doesn't work and I guess the main problem is comparing last and first.

```
int index(vector<int> a)
{
int idx=0; int ans=100; int sum=0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
{
    sum=a[i]+a[i+1];
    if(sum<ans)
        idx=i;
}
if(a[0]+a[a.size()-1]<ans)
    idx=a.size()-1;
return idx;
}
//in main function
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i)
    {
        int idx=index(a);
        if(idx==a.size()-1)
            {a[0]=a[0]+a[a.size()-1];
                ans+=a[0]+a[a.size()-1];
                a.pop_back();
            }
        else
        {
            a[idx]=a[idx]+a[idx+1];
            ans+=a[idx]+a[idx+1];
            a.erase(a.begin()+idx-1);

        }
```

Comment: Do you mean `a[n-1]` and `a[n]`?

Comment: I meant it's a circular array (a[n] and a[0] are adjacent). Sorry if it was'nt clear.

Comment: Better add that info explicitly to the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: What's the question?  Looks like you have half the job done.

Comment: Wait...if you do that until one element remains, then doesn't that just result in one element which is the sum of all the elements?  Is getting there half the fun in your case?

Comment: What have you done? Does it not work? Looks like a "write my code" question.

Comment: @NipunKohli So you have a circular container of `n+1` elements? Otherwise if you have `n` elements you are doing modulo `n` arithmetic and `n%n==0` so `a[0]` is `a[n]`.

Comment: @Wyck maybe he is not adding arithmetic types^^

Comment: @Wyck I'm sorry there's a reason i have to do it that way that will take a while to explain

Comment: On the [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) help page: "Questions _seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?')_ must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." We can't guess the problem with code we can't see.

Comment: edited thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

Since the array is circular, each element in the array may be the first of the adjacent pair with the smallest sum.

So consider each element at index `i`, and its pair at index `j` which is `(i + 1) % n` to find the smallest pair.  ...where `n` is the current number of elements in the vector.  The `% n` will take care of the wraparound, and circular nature of your array.  When `i` is the last element (`n - 1`), then `j` will be the first element (`0`).

Once the indices `i` and `j` of the smallest pair have been determined, replace one of the two elements with the sum, and `erase` the other one.  The convention you apply will determine whether the sum of the first and last elements will be placed at the start or end of the vector.

Repeat this until there is only one element remaining.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

// Just a handy function to display the vector.
void print(std::vector<int> const& input)
{
    std::copy(input.begin(), input.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec{ 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2 }; // some example input data

    print(vec);
    while (vec.size() > 1) {
        // Find the smallest pair of adjacent elements.
        size_t min_i = 0;
        size_t min_j = 1;
        int min_sum = vec[0] + vec[1];
        for (size_t i = 1; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
            size_t j = (i + 1) % vec.size();
            int sum = vec[i] + vec[j];
            if (sum < min_sum) {
                min_i = i;
                min_j = j;
                min_sum = sum;
            }
        }
        // Replace element i with the sum.
        vec[min_i] = min_sum;
        // Erase element at j;
        vec.erase(vec.begin() + min_j);

        print(vec);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3 1 4 1 5 9 2
4 4 1 5 9 2
4 5 5 9 2
5 5 9 6
10 9 6
10 15
25
```

---

#### Edit: OP asked to be shown where they went wrong.

As for your code, there are so many problems and dangerous practices.  :(

First, please recall that the index `[n]` is not valid if there are `n` elements n the array.  Valid indices of an array with `n` elements are `0` through `n-1` inclusive.  So accessing `[i]`and `[i+1]` when `i == n-1` is a *buffer overrun error* because you are accessing elements `n-1` (the last) and `n-1 + 1`, one past the last.

Your code to compute the minimum sum is incorrect in that is updates `sum` (which should be a local) but not `ans`.  Write smaller functions and write unit tests for those functions.  If you had written a function to compute the minimum value of the pairs of the array, you would have seen that it would have failed even the most basic of unit tests.  The code you wrote does not compute the minimum.

Given an array with at least one element, finding the index of the minimum value and its index typically goes like this:

```
int min_val = a[0];
int min_index = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
   if (a[i] < min_val) {
      min_val = a[i];
      min_index = i;
   }
}
```

`100` is not an appropriate initial minimum value (if that's what you intended it to be).  A value like `MAX_INT` is better.  `std::numerical_limits<int>::max()` is better still for modern C++.

You increment `ans` in a loop, which retained a value from the previous usage in the previous loop.  Also, `ans` is not used hereafter in your program.  I suggest you judiciously apply the most restrictive scope possible to your local variables.

You are special casing your wraparound by writing duplicate code with logical checks, which increases the number of opportunities you have to introduce a bug, when instead you should make use of the modulus operator to distill the code path into a single path of execution that handles both the wraparound and nominal cases of adjacency.

And finally, all your algorithm does is compute the sum of an array and store it in a single element.  The approach of removing elements one at a time with `erase` is a performance disaster compared to a direct sum computation.  I'm honouring your request to do it this way because of your "reason", which you didn't disclose, and I still find highly unjustifiable and dubious at this point, unless it's just a learning exercise.

Comment: @NipunKohli I added a review of where you went wrong in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following algorithm:

- Assign one of the elements to be replaced with the new value.
- Erase the other one.

Comment: @NipunKohli Using the `erase` member function.

Comment: `a.erase(a.begin() + 5)` will erase the element at index 5.